# Mistakes on Wikipedia page "Convolution of probability distributions"?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The Wikipedia page on "Convolution of probability distributions" has the following theorem ([link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions)). Suppose we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose PDFs are $f$ and $g$ and CDFs are $F$ and $G$. Then the sum of them $Z = X + Y$ has the CDF
$$
H(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(z-t)g(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(t)f(z-t)dt
$$

I can derive the first formula but I really think the second formula is incorrect. I think it should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(z-t)f(t)dt$ instead. I would appreciate if anyone could support or refute my argument and state their reasoning.

---

If it helps, my derivation is as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
H(z)
 &= \Pr[X+Y\leq z] \\
 &= \Pr[Y\leq z-X] \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Pr[Y\leq z-x]f(x)dx \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(z-x) f(x)dx
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both correct. You obtain one from the other with the substitution $t\to z-t$. Alternatively, you can integrate

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(z-t)g(t)\mathrm dt
$$

by parts, using the fact that $F(z-t)G(t)$ vanishes at both ends.

Comment: I tried both ways and I think you are right. Although getting the right answer involves changing and reversing the range of integral after substituting variables and remembering that $dF(z-t) = (-1)f(z-t)dt$, so it still took me some time to figure out. Thank you!